# How to link two scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon

**Goal :**
I'm doing a firefox add-on. Its purpose is to know when the members of my team - in a game - are logged in.

**What I have :**
I have a **first javascript** which starts when I open the browser. It creates and contains an array of mates objects, and check every minutes if they changed their status.

At the end of this script, I create a button in the toolbar. A click on this button open an HTML page in a popup. I have a **second javascript**, included by `<script>` in the HTML page. Its purpose is to modify the HTML page and in a near future to display who is online.

**Issue :**
The two parts of the add-on work, but **I don't know how to link them**. Require doesn't work in the second script, and I can't include the first one in the HTML page. How can I get my mates array in the second script?

Comment: Use the **port** methods.  See documentation at mdb

Comment: Use code snippets rather than descriptions. The answer to your question is 'interprocess communication'. There are way too many addon APIs in Firefox to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use require:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using#Importing_CommonJS_modules

Or you can use loadSubScript - this is what I do:

```
 Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript(core.addon.path.content + 'modules/cutils.jsm', this);
```

Where `this` is the scope you want to import it into.

You can also use `Cu.import` to import a file, here I do so with a custom jsm file - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9045387